# I am getting theses errors in Django admin can any one help me this

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I am new to Django and i am trying to make custom authentication for my project by while running the server I am Getting these errors please help me to resolve this issue .

```
ERRORS:
<class 'users.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E008) The value of 'fieldsets[1][1]['fields']' must be a list or tuple.
<class 'users.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[1]' refers to 'name', which is not an attribute of 'users.user'.
<class 'users.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'UserAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'users.user'.
```

my admin code is:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib import admin
User=get_user_model()

from  django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

from .forms import UserAdminCreationForm, UserAdminChangeForm
# Register your models here.


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

    list_display = ('name', 'phone', 'admin')
    list_filter = ('staff','active','admin')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields':('phone', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info',{'fields':('name')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields':('admin','staff','active')}),
                 )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide'),
            'fileds': ('phone', 'password1', 'password2',),}
         ),
    )


    search_fields = ('phone','name')
    ordering = ('phone','name')
    filter_horizontal = ()

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(UserAdmin,self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)

admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)

admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages are all very clear and explanatory and tell you exactly what to do.

`fieldsets[1][1]['fields']` is set to `('name')`. This is not a list or tuple, it's just the string `'name'` with parentheses around it. To make it a tuple, it should be `('name',)`, note the comma.

`ordering[1]` is `'name'`, which is not a field on the model. Go look at the model and choose a field that is there. Did you mean `'username'` or `'first_name'`?

`list_display[0]` is again `'name'`, which is again, not a field on the model. Maybe you meant `'username'`?

It really looks like you didn't read the error messages, or don't know enough Python to understand the code you've used, or haven't done the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) or read the [admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/), so I'd suggest taking a breather and reading through those and brushing up on Python and how to debug error messages.